# Test class for converted lead

Tags: apex

Please let us know how to cover the line `oppID.add(convopp.ConvertedOpportunityId);`  in below class.

```
 public class sampleclass 
{
   public static void sampleMethod(List<Lead> convertLeads)
   {
      List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();
      Set<ID> oppid = new Set<ID>();

      List<Lead> leadList = [Select Id,name,ConvertedOpportunityId from Lead where id =:convertLeads  ];

      for(Lead convopp : leadList)
      {
          oppID.add(convopp.ConvertedOpportunityId); // this line is not covering
      }


   }


}
```

> Test class

```
@IsTest 
public class sampleClass_Test {
    static testMethod void test1(){

        Lead l1 = new Lead();
        l1.LeadSource = 'Internal Referral';
        l1.FirstName = 'test1';
        l1.LastName = 'test2';

        l1.Company = 'test';
        l1.Status = 'Qualified';
        insert l1;
        test.startTest();

        Database.LeadConvert Leadconvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
        Leadconvert.setLeadId(l1.Id);
        LeadStatus Leads= [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
        Leadconvert.setConvertedStatus(Leads.MasterLabel);
        Database.LeadConvertResult Leadconverts = Database.convertLead(Leadconvert); 
        System.assert(Leadconverts.isSuccess());

        List<Lead> listLead = new List<Lead>();
        listLead = [select id, ConvertedAccountId, ConvertedOpportunityId, IsConverted from lead where LastName = 'test2'];
        System.debug('listLead ***'+ listLead);
        sampleclass.sampleMethod(listLead);
        test.stopTest();

    }    
}
```

Comment: From where are you calling the `sampleClass` and when is it called?

Comment: I am calling it from trigger, but there is no criteria in trigger. just calling

Comment: You should check if the leads in trigger are **converted** or not using `isConverted` field. Second, if the class above is called from trigger, you don't need to SOQL leads again. Just loop through the leads list and check for their isConverted flag and then add them to your  `oppID` set.